# Firebase messaging in Django template

Tags: django, firebase, django-templates, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to get notifications from firebase using Django templates?

As I understand, there must be a service worker in `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file, that must be in [project root](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive#handle_messages_when_your_web_app_is_in_the_foreground). But how can I do this in Django, if js-scripts goes to the static folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('{% static "js/firebase-messaging-sw.js" %}')
            .then((registration) => {
                var messaging = firebase.messaging();
                messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);  
            }
            });
```

Here is the way to specify the path to the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file